# passing variables with the same name over get

Tags: jquery, forms

I have the following problem. I have a multiselect box. I want to read all the selected variables from multi-select and pass them over HTTP Get.

```
     ajax: {
        url: wwwFullDir + 'api/statistics/',

        data: function (d) {

            var data = $('#form-filter').serializeArray(), filter = {};
            {
                d[data[i].name] = data[i].value;
                console.log(data[i].name + "=" + data[i].value);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the output I'm getting

```
      filter[company] = 1
      filter[company] = 2
      filter[company] = 3
```

Everything so far so good, but the problem is jquery passes only one of the company ID's to the get query, because the variable name is the same:

```
     /api/statistics/?filter[company]=3
```

Should be:

```
    /api/statistics/?filter[company]=1&filter[company]=2&filter[company]=3
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Would it be okay to use a comma-separated list? Like `filter[company]=1,2,3`?

Comment: This `/api/statistics/?filter[company]=1&filter[company]=2&filter[company]=3` is wrong, `filter[company]` will be assigned the last value (`3`). Either join with `,` or create url like `/api/statistics/?filter[company][]=1&filter[company][]=2&filter[company][]=3` here you will have `$_GET[company]` as array

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @u_mulder if I rename the variable to filter[company][] jquery still puts only filter[company][]=3 instead of remaining ID's. The variable name stays the same and is assigned 3 times ether way. Purag's answer solved my problem, make it as an answer and I will accept it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to make it a comma-separated list:

```
filter[company]=1,2,3
```

And in your capture script, change it into an array. If you're using PHP, you could do:

```
$filter = $_GET["filter[company]"];
$companies = explode(",", $filter);
// returns array(1, 2, 3)
```

HOWEVER: I did some research, and it turns out you should be able to do this by setting the `traditional` option of `$.ajax()` to `true`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: wwwFullDir + 'api/statistics/',
  data: function(d){
    // retrieve data
  },
  traditional: true
});
```

There's more on traditional serialization in jQuery [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).